# Custom Property in Azure AD access token

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am new to Azure AD schema extention/custom properties. I have few custom application properties for my application. To get the custom property, I have to call graph API. Is there a way in which my custom properties are included with access token, so I don't have to call Graph API to fetch custom property everytime after decoding token ?

Answer (score 0):

Today that is not possible. Sorry! It is a feature in consideration.

Comment: I think you already have a complete understanding of the feature. There is no way to influence the content of a token outside of the intended usage. Custom attributes are to be retrieved via Graph API calls, but I would not call it a workaround.

Comment: Is there a way I can add additional claims to the token after authentication ? If not, then some kind of caching of claims relative to the token ?

Comment: After authentication, absolutely!!! See http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/26/augmenting-the-set-of-incoming-claims-with-the-openid-connect-and-oauth2-middleware-in-katana-3-x/

Comment: How are you validating tokens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95022/discussion-between-sabby62-and-vibronet).